# How to find a row based on condition and return a column value of this row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe `df`:

```
timestamp          col1
2021-01-11 11:00   0
2021-01-11 12:00   0
2021-01-11 13:00   1
2021-01-11 14:00   1
2021-01-11 15:00   0
```

I need to get a `timestamp` of the first row when `col1` is equal to 1. The expected answer is `2021-01-11 13:00`.

This is my current solution:

```
first = None
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row["col1"] == 1:
        if not first:
            first = row["timestamp"]
            break
```

How can I simplify it and make it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions if match at least one value:

If there is only `0` and `1` values use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
out = df.loc[df['col1'].idxmax(),'timestamp']
```

Or if possible another values like `0, 1` compare by `1`:

```
out = df.loc[df['col1'].eq(1).idxmax(),'timestamp']
```

Or create `DatetimeIndex` first:

```
out = df.set_index('timestamp')['col1'].idxmax()
```

---

```
print (out)
2021-01-11 13:00:00
```

Solution for any values - if no match `idxmax` return first value, so possible solutions:

```
print (df)
            timestamp  col1
0 2021-01-11 11:00:00     0
1 2021-01-11 12:00:00     0
2 2021-01-11 13:00:00     0
3 2021-01-11 14:00:00     0
4 2021-01-11 15:00:00     0


out = df.set_index('timestamp')['col1'].eq(1).idxmax()
print (out)
2021-01-11 11:00:00

s = df.set_index('timestamp')['col1'].eq(1)
out = s.idxmax() if s.any() else None
print (out)
None
```

Comment: @mozway - I tested it and then change

Comment: What is the output of "df.loc[df['col1'].idxmax(),'timestamp']" is all values are 0?

Comment: @Fluxy - then is returned first value of `timestamp`

Comment: @Fluxy This is however less efficient to run `.eq(1)` twice than using my last [proposed approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71351511/16343464)

Comment: @mozway - good idea, added to variable `s`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the index of the first `1` among the 0/1s:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].idxmax(), 'timestamp']
```

Or to get the first `1` in case there are other values:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].eq(1), 'timestamp'].iat[0]
```

output: `'2021-01-11 13:00'`

Ensuring that a value exists:

```
s = df.loc[df['col1'].eq(1), 'timestamp']
s.iat[0] if len(s) else 'no value'
```

or as one liner:

```
s.iat[0] if len(s:=df.loc[df['col1'].eq(1), 'timestamp']) else 'no value'
```

output if no 1: `no value`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loc`

```
df.loc[df.col1 == 1]
```

this will return all row where the condition is met

```
df.loc[df.col1 == 1].timestamp.values[0]
```

will return just the value in the timestamp column for the first row that satisfies the condition